# Storage and presentation of database data across multiple languages

Tags: sql-server, locales, globalization

Apologies if this has been asked before.  After extensive searching I cannot find anything that serves as a solution (a similar answer is posted below).  **I am afraid this is an open-ended (broad) question simply because I don't know what I don't know.  Please don't downvote if not suitable for this site; some pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated instead.**

We have a web application running on SQL Server 2012 with ASP.Net.  There are around 150 tables and 600 stored procedures.  We have successfully managed to manage data across three different languages historically, fortunately because each client only required data in their own language.

For example:

1. Client enters database data from web forms in their own language (using nvarchar/UTF16 across all respective fields)
2. ASP.Net uses resource files to provide the interface in the local language

We now have a prospect who requires a standard set of global database data to be available in 20 languages.  While the interface translation (although a big job) isn't technically difficult, I am struggling to see how this is achieved in SQL Server, and would appreciate any input from people who have achieve this historically.  Given that enterprise-level companies such as Oracle and SAP must do this regularly (I assume), I'm sure it's possible somehow.

A [related answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/161079/18141), albeit for MySQL seems to be feasible...

> Normally I use two tables, main table has default language, just in case you forget to add corresponding values into translations tables.
>
> `create table books (
>       book_id int,
>       book_name varchar(200),
>       description varchar(500)
>   )
>   create table books_language (
>       book_id int,
>       language_id vachar(10),
>       book_name varchar(200),
>       description varchar(500)
>   )`
>
> This returns all records including default language.
>
> `select book_id,
>          isnull(books_language.laguage_id, 'default')
>          isnull(books_language.name, books.name) as name,
>          isnull(books_language.description, books.description) as description
>   from books
>        left join books_language
>        on books.book_id = books_language.book_id`

...but I can't figure out the following practicalities, assuming my database doubles to 300 tables in size.

1. Because each user requires data in their own specific locale, how do you pass every query without doing this dynamically, for the application to bind to the respective display fields?
2. How do you handle a table having 20 data fields, rather than just one as in the example?
3. How do you deal with text searches, when the table required for the data may differ every time?

**Or is there a better way entirely?**

I've tried widgets such as Google Translator and Bing, but they don't work properly.  While they both struggle with data from partial page reloads, they just translate *everything*, and often not very well.  I've also read about plug-in software, although these were for Oracle only.

#### Examples

Take a skills database for example, where peoples' skills are recorded and managed.  The person table won't obviously need translating, and date formats (e.g. date of birth) would be handled by the interface (.Net based on browser settings).  However, the skills table is more complex:

```
Id int,
SkillTitle nvarchar(100),
Description nvarchar(max),
Objectives nvarchar(max)
```

Then there's the table that defines abilities against the skills:

```
Id int,
SkillLevel int, 
Title nvarchar(100),
Description nvarchar(max),
ContextualData nvarchar(max)
```

Basically in my database there's about 70 tables where text-based data would need to be managed in different languages.  Some have a couple of text columns, and some as much as 10.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a lot of this depends on exactly what data elements need to be translated, and at the moment I think you might be focusing too much on technical specifics instead of where the need truly lies.

Given this:

> ASP.Net uses resource files to provide the interface in the local language

what elements need to be translated in the database?

1. Application / System lookup values? Probably not these since the UI is handling that via resource files.
2. User data? No, this wouldn't make sense. If someone fills out a form, they don't expect it to magically appear in 20 different languages.
3. Customer configured lookup values? Possibly, but they would be the ones supplying the translations.

Can you provide 1 or 2 examples of something that would need this structure? It seems that this structure is what would be used if one were not using resource files.

The only globalization issue I can see here is how to handle sorting and comparison according to each user's preferred language, given that many cultures have different rules, even if sharing many / most of the characters. In this respect, you will need to make use of Dynamic SQL because unfortunately you cannot specify collations dynamically (please vote for my suggestion to allow for this: [Allow collation set by variable when using the COLLATE clause (at least in expressions)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36197785-allow-collation-set-by-variable-when-using-the-col) ). But for now (or possibly forever given the likelihood of that request being implemented :-(  ), you will need to attach the `COLLATE` keyword to relevant parts of queries (`WHERE` / `GROUP BY` / `ORDER BY` / etc) based on the current user's language. So one person might get `French_100_CI_AS` and someone else might get `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS`, and so on. This doesn't require multiple fields.

The only thing that different columns for different languages would get you is the ability to index the different collations (i.e. locales). So if there is a place that really needs performance, you can consider specifying the primary language as the collation of the column, and then create non-persisted computed columns that simply return the main column along with a different collation, and then index the non-persisted computed column(s).

If you feel that your app really will need to store multiple languages worth of a single item that would not be handled by the resource files, then please provide at least one, if not two examples. But even if there are some, I can't see how it would ever be all, or even most, columns. Things like customer names don't change based on what language they come from. I mean, I did adopt a Spanish form of my name for Spanish class in Junior High and High School, but that was for class. If I become a customer of a company in a Spanish-speaking country, I will still give them my real name. And the name of my street, city, and state won't change either.

Comment: Thanks for your valued input.  I raised a suggestion to Microsoft about this exact same thing some years ago before the portal was moved to Azure.  Strangely, it never got migrated... I voted on your's anyway.  I've updated the question to provide a crude example.  Sorting isn't really too hard because the .Net interface can handle that natively based on browser locale.

Comment: Is there any way of adding some kind of meta ID/code to each table column that requires translation, then having a single database table that contains the tranlsations for those...?  Just a thought (magic wand wish)...

Comment: @EvilDr Thanks for providing those additional details in the question. I will update soon now that I better understand the overall issue.

Comment: @EvilDr Hi there. Sorry, no, got busy. Regarding the `skills` and `abilities` tables, is the data supplied by you or the user? I am still not sure why resource files would not be the way to go, especially since you are already using them. Clearly you need the tables to track the data, and you need more than IDs in the DB, but it still seems like using English in the DB but having the UI show the correct language based on the ID (even if the English text has to also be in a resource file, for consistency) is best. Are the other languages needed for reports, etc that won't go through the UI?

Comment: @EvilDr Also, regarding "_Sorting isn't ... hard because the .Net interface can handle that natively_": no, no, no. I am not talking about sorting a grid of results, or a drop-down. I am talking about the sorting and comparison that happens with every ORDER BY, GROUP BY, WHERE / JOIN predicate, etc that references these string columns. The UI has no control over how `[Ability].[Description] = LIKE N'%' + @DescriptionContains + N'%'` or `SELECT TOP (100) .... FROM [dbo].[Skill] sk ORDER BY sk.[Title]`, especially if there are 1 million rows. You will need Dynamic SQL to specify `COLLATE ...`.

Comment: Thanks.  We provide the web app as an empty framework, and the client enters their data.  Therefore we can easily translate the interface using ASP.Net built-in Resource File approach (we easily translate the entity titles in the front-end (e.g. `skill title`, etc.). But... the client needs the database data that they enter to be translated into many languages.  We have no control over what `skills` they will create (10 vs 10,000), but they need that data to appear in the end users' native language across 25 countries.  Clearly even despite the technology, this is a *huge* administrative task.

Comment: The example you provide regarding `LIKE N'%' + @DescriptionContains ...` thoroughly backs up the importance of your SQL feedback suggestion.

Comment: @EvilDr Sorry for the delay. Yeah, it occurred to me that this can't be handled via resource files because people will need to search on these values. In which case, looking back at the example from the related question that noted in the question, I would do something similar to the `book` / `book_translated` setup. Except I would probably _not_ include the default columns in the main table. Instead, I think I would put string columns that do _not_ need translating in the main table, and the columns that do need translating in the related table. (continued...)

Comment: @EvilDr I would also use a `TINYINT` for language, unless the languages that the client is using all map to supported locales of Windows collations available in SQL Server, in which case I would use the LCID (`INT`) of the culture / collation as it's a standard value / stable natural key. Definitely `NVARCHAR` for all of multi-language columns, and you will still need to use dynamic SQL to set collation per user's language (so you will need a lookup to map the LCID to preferred collation since there are several per each LCID. Who will translate? Use a service / human, not an automated system.

Comment: Thanks Solomon.  The translation will be done by the client, as and when they can apply the resources and based on priority.  English will always be populated first and would be the "primary" language.  Could you please provide me with a sample schema or fiddle?  I just can't get my brain around how multiple columns can be mapped into the translation tables.  Thanks again.